# How to preserve button background and foreground color on tkinter button when pressed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a button in tkinter that I have coloured the bg/fg to.

I am happy with how it looks however when pressed the button colour reverts to the default black text on a grayish background which I am not happy with.

```
begin_button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='Click me!', bg='blue', fg='red', font='Helvetica 10', command=begin)
```

Is there a simple way fix the colors in place when the button is pressed? I don't mind the button being sunken (in fact that is quite nice) but the color change is not good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust `activebackground` and `activeforeground`, which are responsible for the bg/fg colors of the button when active.

```
begin_button = tk.Button(root, text='Click me!', bg='blue', fg='red', font='Helvetica 10',
                         activebackground="blue",activeforeground="red")
```